# Know when a third branch has been merged to master

Tags: git, github

This might be an easy question for some of you.

Let's say I have a branch which is called feature, and from this branch I create sub branches called sub-features. The right way of merge would be to merge sub-feature in feature and then feature to master.

So here is my question how can I know when (if it has been done already) a sub-feature branch has been merged to master as well. I am doing this manually by chasing merge commits but is a bit tedious and of course might have some human errors.

Good to say sub-feature branches have been removed but of course I have the commits refs.

Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all commits on `subfeature`, but not on `master`, use:

```
git log master..subfeature
```

which is equivalent to:

```
git log subfeature ^master
```

(which can be written as `git log subfeature --not master`)

Of course, both `master` and `subfeature` can be replaced by any commit-ish (branch name, tracking branch, tag, commit hash, …)

If you want to know to which branches a commit has been merged (in other words, answering the question: which branches contain this commit?):

```
git branch --contains commithash
```

Comment: tried this before but throws;
`fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..PTWYNN-619': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: @OmarAyala are `master` and `PTWYNN-619` local branch names? It does not look like it.

Comment: No. Also tried by adding origin like;

`git log origin/subfeature origin/^master`

`git log origin subfeature origin ^master`

but with same result I am afraid.

Also tried with commit ref.

Comment: @OmarAyala If you want to compare to `origin/master` with the latter syntax, it is `^origin/master`. You are negating the ref, not using a different branch name.

Comment: Sorry @knittl. I have tried the way you said it was a typo. However still throws same error. Might the error be thrown becuase subfeature has been mergen in 2 different feature branches that in the end have been merged to master ?

Comment: @OmarAyala Merging to different branches does not matter. But the refs that you want to display have to exist. If they don't, well, you will get the error you see. You can easily check if they exist if you run `git log subfeature` or `git log master`. If you get an error, then this ref does not exist. You either need to create it, or replace it with something else, such as its commit hash (if you know it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230127/discussion-between-omar-ayala-and-knittl).